# To index or not to index – are there reasons to index columns already included in a primary key?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table with a primary key defined on say three columns, is there any point in creating separate additional indexes for each of the three columns?

I have encountered a database at a customer site where they have done this, and it seems to me to be counterproductive because the columns are already indexed courtesy of the clustered PK index, and further indexes add insert overhead without improving search performance.

But then databases are a black art so before making a recommendation I'd like to get wider opinion from t'experts.

Primary concern is Sql Server, but the situation may also arise at sites using Oracle.

Comment: What is the order of the columns in the index and what queries will you be filtering on that you're worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in the body of this Question, yes, there is a point (several, really) in creating an index for only one column, even if that column is part of the primary key. One such point is that the database engine may use a more selective index, particularly if only the columns in that selective index are relevant to the query or commands being executed. One reason why a more-selective index may be used is that for indexes with multiple columns, the order of the columns in the index is important; a multi-column index can't *necessarily* be (easily) used if the first column isn't relevant.

Comment: The scope is this - if a column is indexed by being included in the primary key, is there any advantage in adding a separate index for that column? Your answer appears to be 'generally, yes' which tells me what I need to know. I was always taught the opposite (unless unavoidable only index a column once, even if in a compound index), but that was a long time ago.

Comment: @haughtonomous – maybe just editing the question title then would clarify exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with the title - can you suggest an improvement?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your application you can decide what works best for indexes on the other columns in the table. For example, if you have a large percentage of queries including certain columns it may make sense to include them as indexes. You can include a single index per column or create a "covering index" that may include additional columns that you know will be returned in SQL queries frequently by your application.

Here is some other helpful advice:

1. You can run SQL Management Studio and issue some of your SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries using the "[Display Estimated Execution Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)". This will give you a visual graph of what the DBMS is doing under the covers. If you see "table scans" or "index scans" you can increase performance by adding indexes to change to "table seek" or "index seek" which is much more efficient.
2. You can install a tool called [SQL Performance Dashboard](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29063). This is a fantastic tool that is provided by Microsoft that will actually examine the queries / transactions against your database from your application and provide SSRS reports with suggested hints of where to add indexes, etc. The dashboard reports are available for SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: This isn't correct; a primary key constraint can contain multiple columns.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. In my original post (before I edited) I meant to say that you can only have one primary key. If he is using multiple columns for the primary key the benefits/caveats can still be identified by using the techniques I've included in my answer.

Comment: Interesting. What this means for me is our application (which upgrades its database with each new release if changes are made) cannot predict what indexes may exist on site because customers are free to define their own report queries, and may well add new indexes to improve reporting performance. Hmm....

Comment: @haughtonomous – managing indexes as part of database migrations (changes in the schema) is tough for an application with multiple instances for different clients, especially if the database usage is significantly different among clients. You should, however, be able to maintain pretty-good indexes that should work reasonably well for most clients. And there are ways you could allow customers to maintain their own indexes; tho if you do, I hope you're being paid for your support costs!